# Set Nav Bar's color without using .barTintColor?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, viewdidload

I am trying to display a user picture in place of the `rightBarButton` but setting `barTintColor` of the `UINavigationBar` tints the image.

[image]

In the `AppDelegate`, tried:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .blue
```

In the `viewDidLoad`, tried:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .blue
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .blue
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
```

To set the image:

```
let avatarBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
avatarBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 30, height: 30)
avatarBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"myAvatar")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)

let menuBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: avatarBtn)
menuBarItem.tintColor = .clear

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuBarItem
```

None of these have worked. How can you setup a multi-colored nav bar button without a tint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe this one helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/55121426/10150796

Comment: You can try adding the button on the navigationbar as subview.

Comment: @vivekDas tried that too. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change `tintColor`.

`tintColor` : The tint color to apply to the navigation items and bar button items.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code but in my case i got expected result. Which image type you are using?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .blue
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .blue
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    let avatarBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    avatarBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 30, height: 30)
    avatarBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"myAvatar1")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    let menuBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: avatarBtn)
    menuBarItem.tintColor = .clear
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuBarItem
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your image is still tinted blue. Try a photo with multiple colors.

Comment: @Ryan I have edited my answer with colored image. I don't know why I cant reproduce your issue. I literally copy pasted your code.

Comment: That's really strange. I'm using Swift 5.0 and the image is saved as a PDF. I tried it with a PNG and it seems to work. Any idea what's causing the PDF problem?

Comment: @Ryan I tried with Pdf and it also worked for me . May be you are having issue converting pdf to uiimage. Did you put your pdf in asset catalog? I noticed UIImage(named:)  wont work for pdf images unless you put pdf image in asset catalog.